# Raspistill image tinted

Tags: camera

Raspistill images are tinted and lack colours. I tried removing and carefully inserting both end of the camera ribbon but problem not resolved (same when using motion videos are tinted). When taking images from a usb webcam (using Fswebcam) the colors are normal.

Answer (score 1):

The auto white balance on the camera can be a bit slow and it is sensative to timing and other [options](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md). Use `raspistill --help` for a list of options:

```
Runs camera for specific time, and take JPG capture at end if requested

usage: raspistill [options]

Image parameter commands

-?, --help  : This help information
-w, --width : Set image width <size>
-h, --height    : Set image height <size>
-q, --quality   : Set jpeg quality <0 to 100>
-r, --raw   : Add raw bayer data to jpeg metadata
-o, --output    : Output filename <filename> (to write to stdout, use '-o -'). If not specified, no file is saved
-l, --latest    : Link latest complete image to filename <filename>
-v, --verbose   : Output verbose information during run
-t, --timeout   : Time (in ms) before takes picture and shuts down (if not specified, set to 5s)
-th, --thumb    : Set thumbnail parameters (x:y:quality) or none
-d, --demo  : Run a demo mode (cycle through range of camera options, no capture)
-e, --encoding  : Encoding to use for output file (jpg, bmp, gif, png)
-x, --exif  : EXIF tag to apply to captures (format as 'key=value') or none
-tl, --timelapse    : Timelapse mode. Takes a picture every <t>ms
-fp, --fullpreview  : Run the preview using the still capture resolution (may reduce preview fps)
-k, --keypress  : Wait between captures for a ENTER, X then ENTER to exit
-s, --signal    : Wait between captures for a SIGUSR1 from another process
-g, --gl    : Draw preview to texture instead of using video render component
-gc, --glcapture    : Capture the GL frame-buffer instead of the camera image
-set, --settings    : Retrieve camera settings and write to stdout
-cs, --camselect    : Select camera <number>. Default 0
-bm, --burst    : Enable 'burst capture mode'
-md, --mode : Force sensor mode. 0=auto. See docs for other modes available

Preview parameter commands

-p, --preview   : Preview window settings <'x,y,w,h'>
-f, --fullscreen    : Fullscreen preview mode
-op, --opacity  : Preview window opacity (0-255)
-n, --nopreview : Do not display a preview window

Image parameter commands

-sh, --sharpness    : Set image sharpness (-100 to 100)
-co, --contrast : Set image contrast (-100 to 100)
-br, --brightness   : Set image brightness (0 to 100)
-sa, --saturation   : Set image saturation (-100 to 100)
-ISO, --ISO : Set capture ISO
-vs, --vstab    : Turn on video stabilisation
-ev, --ev   : Set EV compensation
-ex, --exposure : Set exposure mode (see Notes)
-awb, --awb : Set AWB mode (see Notes)
-ifx, --imxfx   : Set image effect (see Notes)
-cfx, --colfx   : Set colour effect (U:V)
-mm, --metering : Set metering mode (see Notes)
-rot, --rotation    : Set image rotation (0-359)
-hf, --hflip    : Set horizontal flip
-vf, --vflip    : Set vertical flip
-roi, --roi : Set region of interest (x,y,w,d as normalised coordinates [0.0-1.0])
-ss, --shutter  : Set shutter speed in microseconds
-awbg, --awbgains   : Set AWB gains - AWB mode must be off
-drc, --drc : Set DRC Level
-st, --stats    : Force recomputation of statistics on stills capture pass
-a, --annotate  : Enable/Set annotate flags or text


Notes

Exposure mode options :
auto,night,nightpreview,backlight,spotlight,sports,snow,beach,verylong,fixedfps,antishake,fireworks

AWB mode options :
off,auto,sun,cloud,shade,tungsten,fluorescent,incandescent,flash,horizon

Image Effect mode options :
none,negative,solarise,sketch,denoise,emboss,oilpaint,hatch,gpen,pastel,watercolour,film,blur,saturation,colourswap,washedout,posterise,colourpoint,colourbalance,cartoon

Metering Mode options :
average,spot,backlit,matrix

Dynamic Range Compression (DRC) options :
off,low,med,high

Preview parameter commands

-gs, --glscene  : GL scene square,teapot,mirror,yuv,sobel
-gw, --glwin    : GL window settings <'x,y,w,h'>
```